# How to output the number of lines created this month in a file

Tags: bash, shell

How can i output or echo the number of lines of a file such as kern.log from /var/log created this month. I heard of using cat, date, grep and wc but I'm a bit confused.

Any answer would be helpful but if you can answer me directly why not.

Btw, output in bash script(.sh)

[EDIT]
cat /var/log/kern.log | grep '[^ ]' | wc -l
ok, this already outputs the number of lines of that kern.log but how do put the date like getting the number of lines on the month of december?

Comment: I guess you need: (1) `man grep`, (2) `man wc`.

Comment: Try to follow @devnull 's suggest and check those `man` pages. Also, give some sample input of your `kern.log` file to help us figure out how and what you can grep.

Comment: lol. just found out so quickly. I used `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -v '^\s*$' | wc -l`. Well, how do i associate `date` there, reading lines from this(current) month?

Comment: @ThisGuy do not add info about your question in comments. Instead, edit the question and give a proper input sample.

Comment: @fedorqui, edited post for clearer question.

Comment: Errr I still would like to see how kern.log looks like.

Comment: Your title suggests that you want to get the line number of the FILES created this month. I think you mean to get the number of the LINES added on the current month. That's not very clear in your question either. Maybe you should reformulate.

Comment: @JessyAmyot, oh sorry, yeah i messed up with the title. i edited it though.

Comment: @ThisGuy: Can you provide a small sample of kernlog file in your question.

Comment: @anubhava here, `Dec  2 23:57:31 ubuntu kernel: [ 7475.272673] ieee80211 phy0: AMPDU status: BA Timeout, seq 3102, in_transit 0`

Comment: Ok good in that case my answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the line number of the lines written this month, you will need to base on the output format of the file.

We can imagine that the lines would look like this:

`Dec 23 22:15:14 ubunix kernel: [ 2320.727997] 8139too 0000:01:04.0: eth0: link down`

Then you just need to do something like:

```
cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -E "^$(date +%b)" | wc -l
```

The `date +%b` outputs the abreviation of the current month (`Dec`).

But, this will only work with the lines formated like my example. You'll need to adapt the `grep` pattern according to the actual output format. You'll probably figure out the right `date` arguments after reading `man date`.

Answer (score 1):

Your date format in `/var/log/kern.log` is still now know but in case it starts with something like `Dec  5` then you can use this simple `grep -c` to count today's lines:

```
> grep -c "^$(date '+%b ')" /var/log/kern.log
912
```

Comment: thanks a lot. below's and your answer have helped me a lot since I'm new to running linux commands.

Comment: You're welcome. Only because you're new in shell scripting I am giving this tip that the long command in other answer has unnecessary multiple unix commands piped in. Both `cat` and `wc -l` are definitely not needed since `grep -c` can do all that in single command.

Answer (score 1):

### Using GNU Find and GNU Date

Assuming that you are rotating your logs with a tool like [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html), you might be able to skip checking dates on each line and simply check the ctime on the logfiles themselves. For example, if you rotate your logs daily at midnight, you could use GNU find and GNU date to find files from the current month. The trickiest part is that you need to handle compressed logs differently from uncompressed logs. In the following code, this is done with a Bash case statement.

```
# Find current month with GNU Date
current_month="$(date -d `date +%Y-%m`-01)"

# Find files from current month.
for file in $(find /var/log -type f -newerct "$current_month"); do
  echo -n "${file}: "
  case "$file" in
    *gz) zcat "$file" | wc -l ;;
      *) wc -l < "$file" ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wc -l /var/log/<FileName>
```

Look into man wc as suggested by devnull. Output from my system is below.

```
parthiban@ubuntu:~$ wc /var/log/kern.log 
5997  80017 580232 /var/log/kern.log
parthiban@ubuntu:~$ wc -l /var/log/kern.log 
5997 /var/log/kern.log
```